# Password-protected trust store created with keytool displays no entries if no password provided

Tags: java, keytool, truststore

I am struggling with a difference in behavior between the way keytool creates a keystore (used as a trust store here) and imports a trusted certificate, VS the way other tools (e.g. [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/), [kse](https://keystore-explorer.org/index.html)) do the same.

Consider this command:

```
keytool -import -alias myAlias -file ./my_exported_server_cert.crt \
-keystore ./my_truststore.jks
```

This will prompt me for a password, then create `my_truststore.jks` containing the certificate.

Now, if I look inside, and provide the right password, the `myAlias` entry will be listed:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore ./my_truststore.jks -storeType jks -storepass myPass
```

or, programmatically...

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("./my_truststore.jks"))) {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
    keyStore.load(is, "myPassword".toCharArray());
    Iterator<String> it = keyStore.aliases().asIterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

However, if I *don't* provide a password (i.e. remove the `storepass` parameter from the `keytool` call and type return when prompted, or invoke `load` with `null` as the second argument in Java code), no entries are listed.

`keytool` provides a warning, but lists no entries.

Now if I generate a trust store and import the certificate the same way with either portecle or kse, set a password, and run the checks again without providing a password, `myAlias` is still listed as an entry (`keytool` displays a warning as expected, but does also display the certificate).

My debatable understanding of the matter is that a password is less relevant to *read* the contents of a trust store (without much investigation I am also assuming that is why [TrustManagerFactory#init](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/TrustManagerFactory.html#init(java.security.KeyStore)) does not take a password, contrary to [KeyManagerFactory#init](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/KeyManagerFactory.html#init(java.security.KeyStore,char%5B%5D))).

**My question**

- What is the reason for the difference in behavior? Aren't those tools using the same core APIs as `keytool` behind the scenes?
- Is there a way to parametrize `keytool` in order to generate a trust store that allows read visibility on the entries when queried with no password, as the other tools do?

**Notes**

I have replicated this behavior with `keytool` from:

- Oracle JDK 11
- Oracle JDK 12
- OpenJDK11

When testing with `keytool` from Oracle JDK8, I notice the entry is found, although I get warnings when initially creating the keystore server-side, and also exporting the one certificate:

> The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to
>   migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool
>   -importkeystore -srckeystore ./ora8_keystore.jks -destkeystore ./ora8_keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12"

Furthermore, the SSL handshake using the truststore generated with `keytool` from Oracle JDK8 seems to just hang forever with no traces of failure.

While debugging my Java code, I noticed the truststores generated by either tool and either JDK (including Oracle JDK8) were ultimately initialized through the factory as a dual format key store regardless of the factory argument used (`jks`), i.e. the keystore object was of class `sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS`, with an spi having `primaryType = JKS` and `secondaryType = PCKS12`.

That last bit doesn't really help me understand, but it might be relevant somehow.

Comment: This is not my experience over 20 years.

Comment: @user207421 it should be pretty simple to replicate. Have you tried the specific scenario?

Comment: A I already indicated, I've been doing all these things for 20+ years. All you get when not supplying the password is (1) inability to access private keys and (2) non-verification of the keystore structure.

Comment: @user207421 that's how I would expect it to work, yes. And yet I can replicate the "missing entry" part both with `keytool list` or programmatically, when the trust store has been created with keytool and the certificate imported with keytool, at least with java 11 and onwards.

Comment: I've a similar issue, please let me know if you found the answer. My issue is just one of the  trust stores doesn't list all certificates in it without the password. When I list it with the correct password it lists the contents correctly.

Comment: @AmitS that looks very similar indeed. Unfortunately I still have no proper solution for this, although I suspect a change coming from later Oracle Java versions (and propagating to openJDK). My workaround was as follows:

Comment: @AmitS since my context is typically interactive, I check whether the trust store appears to be empty and if so, prompt the user to type a password. If it still appears empty after that, I can inform the user that either the password is wrong, or the trust store really is empty.

Comment: @AmitS of course this would not work well if somehow, only *some* certificates are visible - I haven't bumped into that corner case yet, but that would be a bit of a disaster for me :S

Comment: Thanks @Mena for the prompt reply. I'm struggling to even reproduce it with other truststores, I created the CSR last week, submitted certificate request, imported the generated certificate and this one doesn't list content without password but all previous ones and new ones open properly.

Comment: @Mena Just wanted to update, mine issue was related with JDK10 (JKS was created using it) vs JDK8 (default Java version, used on terminal to list the KS). If I use JDK8 to create and list JKS it works fine. I had actually upgraded JDK and JRE in my IDE while generating the problematic JKS.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is best described in the open JDK bug
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8194702.
We do not have a fix for this problem yet.